# Vertical projection and horizontal projection

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr

I'm trying to implement the following algorithm for ocr in that paper.

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1707/1707.00800.pdf

I'm confused about that part:

[image]

[image]

I constructed the vertical profile of an image:

```
env = np.sum(img, axis=1)
```

[image]

and that's What I get

[image]

I'm looking for a clear explanation of the algorithm, maybe with a pseudo code

Comment: That histogram is supposed to count pixels inside the letters. Your background ha as high value and foreground a low value. Just invert the image and sun again, you’ll see a graph more like in the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, this algorithm is designed to separate individual Arab letters, which when written are connected via a horizontal line (I have exactly zero knowledge in Arab letters).

So the algorithm assumes that the given image is horizontally aligned (otherwise it won't work), and it is looking for areas with similar upper bonds of the black pixels.

After you have constructed the vertical profile of an image, you just need to find the most common height within the word (second highest in the image). Than you just separate the image between areas of that specific height and the rest.

Using your image:

[image]

The red line is the second most common height that you need to find (can be done with a histogram).

The green lines represent the separations between individual characters (so here you will get 4 characters).

By the way, your image is much more noisier and distorted than the one used in the paper, so you should probably find some range of values to discretize your height values to (for example with an histogram).

Pseudo-code (or unconfirmed untested code):

```
# Discretize the y values to n_bins (noisier image will mean you can use less bins):
height_hist = np.histogram(y, bins=n_bins)

# Find bin with the second largest number of values:
bin = np.argsort(height_hist[0])[-2]

# Get the limit values of the bin:
y_low, y_high = height_hist[1][bin], height_hist[1][bin+1]

# Go over the vertical projection values and separate to characters:

zero = y[0] # Assuming the first projected value is outside of the word
char_list = []
i = 0
inside_char = False
while i < len(y):
    if y[i] != zero:
        start = i # start of char

        # Find end of current char:
        for j in range(i, len(y)):
            if y_low<=y[i] and  y[i]<=y_high:
                end = j # end of char
                char_list.append([start, end]) # add to char list
                i = end

        # Find the start of the next char:
        for j in range(i, len(y)):
            if y_low>y[i] or  y[i]>y_high:
                i = j
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks voted up, Can you please show some pseudo code of the algorithm, it will be very helpful post in stackoverflow!. Very knowledgable :).

Comment: ```Than you just separate the image between areas of that specific height and the rest.```  Can you explain that more, hopefully in pseudo code

Comment: what is the input for the histogram ? The vertical summation ? and what is Y ? is Y the vertical projection of the image ?

Comment: for example the height histogram, has different resoultion than the vertical projection of the image.. like the ylow, yheigh is in range of hundreds, but the vertical projection is in range of thousands

Comment: Hello Mark, I have problems formulating the char_list indices.. Can you show me in pseudo code how to get the cuts back from that list into an image of rects ?

Comment: please help me with this issue, I tested your code and it works fine except that I want to cut the image aparts using that char list 2D Matrix

Comment: When you have time please tell me the approach or some pseudo code.. I get the char list as indices, but don't know how to use them to cut out the charachters

Comment: You can just tell me the procedure and I will continue.. Please give me something :)

Comment: From the previous code you should get a list of [start, end], where the first integer is the x coordinate of the start of a char and the second is the end of it. For the y values you should take the max and min values from your projection graph (the same for all chars). Now just crop the image for every char: image[start[i]:end[i],y_min:y_max]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wrote the following but it doesn't work at all.

 for x0, x1 in char_list:

        image_slice=img[x0:x1, int(y_low):int(y_high)]

        plt.imshow(image_slice)
        plt.show()

Comment: I get char list with length 38 for a sample image, and the coordinates are list of list, I can't know which is the start and end for a specific character, the list has start with end coordinates that has small difference. Can you update the code please ?

Comment: I really think that at this point you should be able to fine-tune and fix it on your own or post a new question with your new problems. The code I wrote for this question, as stated is pseudo code. It was written without any knowledge of the structure of your image/graph/script.

Comment: I posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871001/slicing-an-image-based-on-vertical-project  Hope that you answer it